# How to tell doctrine to ignore Memcached if server is offline?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, memcached

I'm testing Memcached on my Symfony2 application
I set it to cache doctrine's queries, results and metadata:

```
orm:
    entity_managers:
        default:
            metadata_cache_driver:
                type: service
                id: doctrine.cache.memcache2
            query_cache_driver:
                type: service
                id: doctrine.cache.memcache2
            result_cache_driver:
                type: service
                id: doctrine.cache.memcache2

services:
    memcache:
        class: Memcache
        calls:
            - [ addserver, [ 'localhost', 11211 ]]

    doctrine.cache.memcache2:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache
        calls:
            - [setMemcache, [@memcache]]
```

Until now, everything works fine.

I was wondering how does doctrine behaves if the Memcached server goes down. As far as I could see, the application breaks. In dev mode I get the following message:

> Notice: MemcachePool::get(): Server localhost (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>   (10060)
>   500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

In production mode I'm also presented with an http 500.

Is there a way to tell doctrine to bypass/ignore the Memcached server and go directly to the database, instead of returning 500s?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `The Second Level Cache` available in doctrine/orm 2.5

see:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/second-level-cache.html

The idea to keep you default options for orm and add a memcache as second level cache:

```
  orm:
     entity_managers:
        default:
           auto_mapping:  true
           second_level_cache:
               region_cache_driver:
                  type:                 service
                  id:                   doctrine.cache.memcache2
               enabled:              true
               regions:
                  region_name:
                       cache_driver:
                           type:                 service
                           id:                   doctrine.cache.memcache2
```

When turned on, entities will be first searched in cache and if they are not found, a database query will be fired and then the entity result will be stored in a cache provider.

Comment: I tested your solution and although it looks good, I can't see the application using the Memcache server... Is the Second Level Cache used in dev mode? Is it necessary to specify the region "region_name" as my region in the entity's @Cache annotation?

Comment: I got the second level cache working. But the behavior is the same. The moment Memcached is killed, the requests return 500.